# Deriving a first-order condition and plotting it generates some outliers

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

When I run this code:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 1; beta = 0.6; W = 60; i = 0.05;
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda));
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
b[e_] := (a W ((1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda - 1) - 1))/\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)] - 1\)]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\);
brf[a_, w_] = ArgMax[{v, e >= 0, e <= 1, Uem > Uun}, e];
Plot[{brf[0.4, w]}, {w, 0, 6}]
```

I get this:

[image]

I have two questions.

1. Why do I have the error messages? And what can I do differently to avoid them?
2. Why do I have those outliers circled in red? How do I know what's causing them and avoid them?

**Edit**: In response to AccidentalFourierTransform's comments below, I made two revisions in my code. First, I made some changes in the $\Sigma$ term in a way that the upper part of $\Sigma$ becomes an integer while not losing the information in the upper part. Second, since `e=1` makes the `1/(1-e)` term and the `1/lambda` term diverge, I replaced `e<=1` by `e<=0.99` as well as adding some other constraints on `L` and `lambda`. So the entire new code is this:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
n = 1; beta = 0.6; W = 60; i = 0.05;
v = ((i + lambda) Uem - (-1 + e) Uun)/(i (1 - e + i + lambda));
L = (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda = ((1 - e) n L)/(1 - e n L);
Uem = w - 1/(w (1 - e));
Uun = b[e] - 1/b[e];
b[e_] := (a W ((1 + i)^(1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda ) - 1))/(\!\(\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 0\), \(Max[IntegerPart[\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(lambda\)]] - 1, 0]\)]\(\((1 + i)\)^j\)\) - 1 + (1 + i)^(1/lambda));
brf[a_, w_] = ArgMax[{v, e >= 0, e <= 0.99, Uem > Uun, L > 0, L < 1, lambda > 0, lambda < 1}, e];
Plot[{brf[0.4, w]}, {w, 0, 6}]
```

which yields

[image]

This shape of plot is not what I was expecting, so I think something is wrong in the code. FYI, what I am expecting is something similar to the concave part of the first diagram.
By the way, once I'm successful with generating a right plot, I'm planning to vary the parameter values to see how the plot would change accordingly.

Comment: what does $\sum _{j=1}^{\frac{1}{\text{lambda}}-1} (i+1)^j$ mean? 1/lambda is not in general an integer. Also, for $e$ close to $0$ or $1$, $1/\lambda$ diverges so most expressions become meaningless.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, I added in the post what I tried following your suggestion which however wasn't successful. Please see the edit part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clean up your code a little bit, first:

```
L[w_, e_, a_] := (w/(beta (a e)^beta))^(1/(beta - 1));
lambda[w_, e_, a_] := ((1 - e) n L[w, e, a])/(1 - e n L[w, e, a]);
b[w_, e_, a_] := (a i (-1 + (1 + i)^(-1 + 1/(1 - e) + 1/lambda[w, e, a])) W)/(-1 - i + (1 + i)^(1/lambda[w, e, a]));
Uun[w_, e_, a_] := b[w, e, a] - 1/b[w, e, a];
Uem[w_, e_] := w - 1/(w (1 - e));
v[w_, e_, a_] := ((i + lambda[w, e, a]) Uem[w, e] - (-1 + e) Uun[w, e, a])/(i (1 - e + i + lambda[w, e, a]));
```

Then, you can define the function

```
B[w_, a_] := If[.1 < 0.04 - 0.23 Sqrt[a] + (1.61 + 0.015/a^2 + 0.31 Sqrt[a]) w + (-1 + 1.4/(0.025 + a^(3/2))) w^2 < .9, FindRoot[Uem[w, e] == Uun[w, e, a], {e, 0.04 - 0.23 Sqrt[a] + (1.61 + 0.015/a^2 + 0.31 Sqrt[a]) w + (-1 + 1.4/(0.025 + a^(3/2))) w^2, .1, .9}, WorkingPrecision -> 40][[1, 2]], If[w >= 3 a, FindRoot[Uem[w, e] == Uun[w, e, a], {e, 0.966 + 0.005 a + 0.048 a^2 + (0.04 - 2.94 a)/(-1.26 + 5.47 Sqrt[a] - 2.66 a - 7.96 a^2 + w^2), .01, .99}, WorkingPrecision -> 40][[1, 2]]]]
```

Such that

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[B[w, a], {a, .1, 1, .1}], {w, 0, 6}, MaxRecursion -> 10] // Quiet
```

produces

[image]

The random stuff on the left part of the plot is not a numerical artifact, it is in fact the correct solution to the maximization problem.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems your code looks a lot different from my original code. For example: Where is $\Sigma$ in the `b[]` function? Why is the `B[]` function a solution to `Uem[]==Uun`? And I couldn't understand how the `B[]` function is constructed with all those numbers. In particular, as my eventual goal is to plot `B[w, .1], B[w, .2], B[w, .3],......, B[w, .9]`, it would be nice to make the code more general instead of making it in terms of specific numbers. Can you please help on these?

Comment: I really appreciate taking time to help, but one thing is that I am trying to have some variations in the parameter values `n = 1; beta = 0.6; W = 60; i = 0.05;` to see how the results would change. But it seems these parameter values are already incorporated in your code which makes it impossible to vary them. Would it be possible to make the parameter values explicit instead of being merged into the code? By the way, I just made some updates on the code in the Edit part to better reflect your comments. Can you use them please? Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code generates an empty graph.

Comment: @ppp Made a typo when copying+pasting, should work now. As for varying the parameters, that's not something my code is going to help with...

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. If you can help me construct a code so that I can vary the parameters, that would be greatly appreciated. And by the way, it is strange but I still get an empty graph from your code.